# Jupyter notebook Slides scrolling Issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scroll, slide

I faced the issue of jupyter notebook slides scrolling issue which was auto disabled.

I got the problem solved by installing

1. pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
2. Open jupyter notebook --> Go to File --> nbconfigurations--> scroll Checked True

Comment: What is your question? You can answer your own question, but there first needs to be a question. stackoverflow has a strict separation between questions and answers, so when you do post an answer, do so as an answer, not in the actual question. See the [tour].